# Use array to add total number of errors per department in Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm not sure how to explain this since the plan/idea is mostly in my head since I don't know how to execute it, but I'll try (comment with questions!):

I have a sheet that lists which department of "my" company made an error, which type of error, and how many of that specific error in the department per fiscal month. (See attachment) [image: sample of the sheet].

I would like to write a macro that would add up the total number of errors (column E) per department (column D) (month or type of error is not a factor in this macro). I've been experimenting with an array/For Next loop using vlookup to the number of entries, but to no avail since I don't have enough experience with arrays. Any ideas? Here's what I've started:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Sub Total_Errors()
Dim Assembly() As Double, CSR() As Double
'... more dept names
Dim i As Integer, RowCount As Integer

RowCount = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

ReDim Assembly(1 To RowCount) As Double, CSR(1 To RowCount) As Double 
' ... more redimmed dept names

Assembly(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("Assembly", Range(Range("D" & i + 1), Range("E" & RowCount)), 2, False)
    Range("H2").Value = Assembly(i)

For i = 2 To RowCount
    Assembly(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("Assembly", Range(Range("D" & i + 1), Range("E" & RowCount)), 2, False)
    Range("H2").Value = Assembly(i - 1) + Assembly(i)
Next i

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, it will only do as I told it and only add the previous value to the current value :p funny how that works. Anyways, what i'd like to have happen with this code is that it will simply add a value to the previous value in the cell. The add method has seemed to be more involved that what I'm trying to do.
All suggestions welcome, and thanks in advance!

Comment: I would strongly advise using a Pivot Table if your goal is just aggregation and analysis.  Regarding why your code does not produce correct results, it is very difficult to determine since this is not a standard way of doing this, and I'm confused what you expect to be in `Assembly(i)`.  If you really want VBA, you would do better with `AutoFilter` and counting visible cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it; it was a lot simpler then I thought it'd be haha. Thanks anyways :)

```
Sub TotalErrors()
Dim Assembly As Single, CSR As Single, Customer As Single, Drums As Single
' ... more departments

Dim i As Integer, RowCount As Integer

RowCount = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To RowCount
    If Range("D" & i).Value = "Assembly" Then
        Assembly = Range("H2").Value + Range("E" & i).Value
        Range("H2").Value = Assembly
    ElseIf Range("D" & i).Value = "CSR" Then
        CSR = Range("H3").Value + Range("E" & i).Value
        Range("H3").Value = CSR
    ElseIf Range("D" & i).Value = "Customer" Then
        Customer = Range("H4").Value + Range("E" & i).Value
        Range("H4").Value = Customer
    ElseIf Range("D" & i).Value = "Drums" Then
        Drums = Range("H5").Value + Range("E" & i).Value
        Range("H5").Value = Drums
' ... more departments
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem easily without VBA. Just try the worksheet function SUMIF. Entering
`=SUMIF(D:D; D1; E:E)`
in cell F1 and copying this formula into each cell in column F gives you the number of errors for the department in each row.

Then you can copy rows D and F as values to a new worksheet and apply the "remove duplicates" feature to create the list of unique departments with their respective error counts.